# Can I make Xamarin Image AspectFit crop rather than pad?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to put a company logo at the top of an About screen. My graphic designer says "make it 40% of the screen width. So I code `Image Aspect="AspectFit"` and put it in Column 1 of a Grid with `ColumnDefinitions="3*,4*,3*"`. Voila! It is 40% of the screen width. But AspectFit "Letterboxes the image (if required) so that the entire image fits into the display area, *with blank space added to the top/bottom or sides* depending on whether the image is wide or tall." So I end up with a heck of a lot of padding above and below the image, depending on how wide the screen is. I have a kludge solution -- coding `RowDefinitions="120"` but is there a way to do this that will work correctly every time, rather than being a kludge that is more or less good enough most of the time? Is there a way to get Xamarin Forms to crop rather than pad?

VS 2019 Community on Windows 10 Pro 64. Target platforms Android, iOS and UWP.

Comment: Try `AspectFill` or set Column 1 to `Auto`? If those don't suit you, you have to define the width to suit the ratio of the image, I'm afraid.

Comment: Column 1 at 40% of the total is a given. That is the whole point. The designer wants the logo to be 40% of the screen width. AspectFill doesn't cut it: as documented, it chops about a quarter of the logo off of each side.

Comment: Would it make any sense to query the actual width from code and set the grid row height to a fixed fraction of that, maintaining the original height/width ratio? Do it from OnLayoutChanged?

Answer (score 1):

And the answer is ... you apparently need to do it in code:

```
private void OnAboutPageLayoutChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const double heightRatio = 200.0 / 600.0 ;        // Ratio of image height to width
    GridLogo.RowDefinitions[0].Height = ImageLogo.Width * heightRatio;
}
```